# how to use parse xml android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

All I want to do is simply read one line out of an XML file. I cant seem to get anything but null. I want to just read the session id right out of the document without creating massive amounts of code. There has to be a super simple way that works.

```
<loginResponse>
   <status message="Success" code="Success"/>
   <sessionid>d713868c-608b-440f-a708-5b7055e2e8d2</sessionid>
</loginResponse>
```

```
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
            inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
            Document doc = db.parse(inStream);


            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("sessionid");
            Node node = nodeLst.item(0);
            String sessionID = node.getTextContent();

            mDbHelper.createAccount(userName, password, sessionID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is use Scanner class.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(stream);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    if(line.startsWith("\t<sessionid>"))
    {
        System.out.println(line.substring("\t<sessionid>".length()));
    }
 }
```